# Does Spanish "estribo" come from English "stirrup"?

Tags: etimología, inglés, lingüística

In [a Linguistics.SE question I asked some time ago](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/24394/what-came-first-starboard-or-estribor), someone made this comment:

> Sounds as if the Spanish [*estribor*] has been folk-etymologised to refer to 'estribo' - **I wonder if that in turn is a borrowing from English '[stirrup](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stirrup)'**?

I thought nothing of it back then, but today I decided to check that claim and I was surprised to find out that **the current DLE entry for *estribo* is marked as "of uncertain origin"**:

> **[estribo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=GzWj5od)**.
>   **De or. inc.**
>
> 1. m. Pieza de metal, madera o cuero, que pende de la ación y en la que el jinete apoya el pie.
> 2. ... etcétera.

Now, it's not that far-fetched to think that *estribo* and *stirrup* are related (somewhat similar pronunciation, and apparently similar roots), but surely the RAE would have noticed by now??

**Is there any info available that supports the claim Spanish *estribo* comes from English *stirrup* or at least from the same Germanic / PIE root?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues veamos. Aunque ahora mismo esté *estribo* marcada como de origen incierto, sí que ha tenido algunas etimologías propuestas a lo largo del tiempo. La primera aparece en el diccionario de Rosal de 1611:

> [...] parecen del Gr. stíbo, o stíbéo, que significan pisar y apretar el pie, hacer fuerza y detener.

En todo caso, las etimologías del doctor Francisco del Rosal no terminan de convencerme. En las primeras ediciones del DLE no se dice nada, pero durante gran parte del siglo XX (desde 1939 hasta 1970) se tuvo por origen el siguiente:

> Del alto alemán *streban*, apoyarse.

En 1984 pasó a:

> Del germánico **strinps*, **strenp*.

Y desde 1992 se considera de origen incierto. El hecho de que al menos se haya considerado la etimología alemana le da un cierto margen de probabilidad de que sea cierta. Por otro lado, si miramos la [etimología de *stirrup*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stirrup), vemos:

> Middle English *stirop*, from Old English *stigrāp*, from *stig-* (akin to Old High German *stīgan* to go up) + *rāp* rope

Así que la palabra española se propone que viene del alto alemán *streban*, mientras que la inglesa vendría de la raíz *stig-* del mismo idioma. Las palabras son similares, lo que podría indicar una raíz común con *st-*, como por ejemplo *[steygʰ-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/steyg%CA%B0-)*, con el significado de "pisar" o "trepar", origen de palabras como *stair* en inglés.

Nótese en todo caso que esto son probabilidades, debido a la actual clasificación de la palabra como de origen incierto.

Comment: *[Stirrup](http://www.etymonline.com/word/stirrup)* de hecho sí viene de la misma raíz que *stair*. No puedo encontrar rastro de *streban* online; sólo *streben*, que equivale al inglés *strive* "luchar, esforzarse".

Comment: Por otro lado, *Strebe* en alemán moderno significa un montón de cosas del tipo de "apoyo, soporte" (especialmente en arquitectura e ingeniería)...