# ¿De dónde viene el significado de "estribillo"?

Tags: etimología

Al ver la pregunta [Does Spanish "estribo" come from English "stirrup"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22925/does-spanish-estribo-come-from-english-stirrup) he pensado si la palabra *estribillo* que parece tener la misma raiz tendría algo que ver, al parecer sí que están relacionadas como podemos ver en el DLE:

> [**estribillo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GzV3CkN)
>
> Del dim. de *estribo*.
>
> 1. m. Expresión o cláusula en verso, que se repite después de cada estrofa en algunas composiciones líricas, que a veces también empiezan
>    con ella.
> 2. m. Voz o frase que por hábito vicioso se dice con frecuencia.

Las definiciones nada tienen que ver con las de *estribo* y sin embargo proviene del diminutivo de esta palabra.

¿Cómo llego *estribillo* a significar estrofa que se repite en composición lírica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El *Diccionario de Autoridades* (tomo III, 1732) parece darnos la respuesta directamente en este caso. Sabemos que un *[estribo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GzWj5od)* sirve para poner y apoyar el pie, para ayudarnos a subir a (o a bajar de) un caballo o a un coche o carroza.

Veamos la definición de *estribillo* que nos da el mencionado diccionario:

> ESTRIBILLO. s. m. Introducción o principio de la letra y composición poética: como Villancico, xácara y otras semejantes que regularmente se suelen poner en música y cantar en las festividades solemnes de la Iglesia. Parece haverse assi llamado porque sirve de pié y motivo en que estriba la tal composición.

No es exactamente la definición de estribillo que conocemos hoy día, aunque sí que es cierto que dice que a veces las canciones comienzan con el estribillo (como el ejemplo citado de los villancicos). Los estribillos, si lo piensas, son el sustento principal de la canción, la parte de la que la gente se suele acordar más. Acordarte del estribillo te da pie para que te acuerdes del resto de la canción (la composición *[estriba](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GzLpfCn)* en el estribillo: descansa, se apoya en él). De ahí que el estribillo se denomine así por ser un pequeño estribo (apoyo, sustento) para el resto de la canción.

Comment: No esperaba una respuesta tan rápida y definitiva :)

Comment: @blonfu es que cuando miré la definición de _estribo_ vi también la de _estribillo_, y me resultó curiosa la relación entre ambas palabras (vamos, que la tenía resuelta antes de que tú preguntaras).